# Initialization from incompatible pointer type warning

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures

I am trying to make an array of pointer pointers to point in an stuct.
until now I have the following code done

```
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct ID{
    char firstName[21];
    char lastName[21];
    char phoneNumber[11];
}ID;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int answere,i=0;
    printf("******* WELCOME TO PHONEBOOK **********\n\n\n");
    printf("***************************************\n");
    printf("*                MENU                 *\n");
    printf("*                                     *\n");
    printf("* 1.Add New   2.Print list     3.Exit *\n\n");
    printf("***************************************\n\n");
    ID* ptr=(int*)malloc(21*sizeof(ID));
    do
    {
        printf("Please select (1, 2 or 3): ");
        scanf("%d",&answere);
        if(answere!=1 && answere!=2 && answere!=3)
        {
            printf("//...Error...\\ please give me a correct answere: ");
        }
        if(answere == 1)
        {
            i++;
            addNew(&ptr,i);
        }
        else if(answere==2)
        {
            PrintList(&ptr,i);
        }
    }while(answere!=3); 

    return 0;
}
```

so the ptr array gonna be each time a new user and I want it to max out at 3 users the code for adding a new user is the following

```
ID addNew(ID *ptr,int i){
    char fname,lname,phone;
    if(i<3)
    {   
        int l;
        for (l=1;l<=3;l++)
        {
            ID user;
            ptr[l] = user;
            printf("enter the first name:   ");
            scanf("%s",&fname);
            *ptr->firstName= fname;
            printf("enter the last name:    ");
            scanf("%s",&lname);
            *ptr->lastName = lname;
            printf("enter the phone number: "); 
            scanf("%s",&phone);
            *ptr->phoneNumber = phone;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("sorry but you have reach max capacity\n");  
    }
}
```

the problem is that when I am calling the first fuction after the assignment of values the programm crashes. What is wrong?

Comment: Why is the title of your question not mentioned in the question itself? Which problem are you actually asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function prototype `ID addNew(ID *ptr,int i)`, so you must call it with `addNew(ptr,i)`, not using `&ptr` because you've already declared `ptr` as `ID*`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you scan a string into a single character. which probably results in memory overrung and thus the behavior of your program is UNDEFINED

```
scanf("%s",&fname); // here fname is only 1 char long, probably a mistake
```